# DataLoader worker (pid(s) 6576) exited unexpectedly

Tags: dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I got this error for the code

dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch-size = 4, shuffle = True, num_workers=1)

Answer (score 0):

I decreased num_workers from 1 to 0 and it worked for me.